# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{\sqrt{(s+a)^3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

Trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s}{\sqrt{(s+a)^3}}$. So solving $\oint_B dz \: \frac{z}{\sqrt{(z+a)^3}} e^{z t}$ (Bromwich contour). I tried doing a u-substitution with $u=z+a$ but that gave me a non converging integral. Is there a better way to approach this problem or was something wrong with my substitution?

Comment: Do you need to compute the transform directly? Usually people try to use a table and reverse the transform without explicitly computing the integral.

Comment: See under [case 2, branch points](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c916.html).

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{s}{\sqrt{(s+a)^3}}=\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s} \left(\dfrac{2(2a+s)}{\sqrt{a+s}}\right)$.

Answer (score 3):

For this one, I would express the ILT as

$$s (s+a)^{-3/2} = (s+a)^{-1/2} - a (s+a)^{-3/2}$$

Now recognize that

$$\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds\, (s+a)^{-1/2} e^{s t} = \frac{e^{-a t}}{i 2 \pi} \int_{a+c-i \infty}^{a+c+i \infty} ds\, s^{-1/2} e^{s t}$$

The latter integral has been evaluated using a modified Bromwich contour as follows.  Consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{z t}}{\sqrt{z}}$$

where $C$ is a keyhole contour that goes up and back around the negative real axis and encircles the origin from $\arg{s}=\pi$ to $\arg{s}=-\pi$.  By the residue theorem (or Cauchy's integral theorem), this integral is zero because there are no poles within $C$.  $C$, however, has $5$ pieces: the original integral along $\Re{s}=a$, a circular arc of large radius $R$, a section that goes in a positive direction just above the negative real axis, a circular arc of small radius $r$ around the origin, and another section just below the negative real axis in a negative direction.  In the limit as $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $ r \rightarrow 0$, the integrals along the circular arcs vanish.  This leaves

$$ \int_{a+c-i\infty}^{a+c+i\infty} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{\sqrt{s}}+e^{i \pi} \int_{\infty}^0 dx \frac{e^{-x t}}{i \sqrt{x}} + \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x t}}{-i \sqrt{x}}=0$$

A little rearranging produces

$$ \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{a+c-i\infty}^{a+c+i\infty} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{\sqrt{s}} = \frac{1}{ \pi}  \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x t}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Substitute $y=\sqrt{x}$ into the integral on the RHS and finally get

$$ \frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{a+c-i\infty}^{a+c+i\infty} ds \frac{e^{s t}}{\sqrt{s}} =  \frac{2}{ \pi}  \int_0^{\infty} dy \; e^{-t y^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}$$

To get the second piece, note that

$$\frac{a}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds\, (s+a)^{-3/2} e^{s t} = \frac{a e^{-a t}}{i 2 \pi} \int_{a+c-i \infty}^{a+c+i \infty} ds\, s^{-3/2} e^{s t}$$

Note that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a+c-i \infty}^{a+c+i \infty} ds\, s^{-3/2} e^{s t} = \int_{a+c-i \infty}^{a+c+i \infty} ds\, s^{-1/2} e^{s t}$$

so that

$$\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{a+c-i \infty}^{a+c+i \infty} ds\, s^{-3/2} e^{s t} = \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\pi t}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}$$

Putting this all together, and noting that this has been done only for $t \gt 0$, we have

$$\frac{1}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \,  s (s+a)^{-3/2} = \left (\pi t\right)^{-1/2} (1-2 a t) e^{-a t} \theta(t)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{\int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
     {s\expo{st} \over \root{\pars{s + a}^3}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
     =\int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
     s\pars{s + a}^{-3/2}\expo{st}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\,,\quad\gamma > \verts{a}\ \mbox{and}\ t > 0.\quad}$

> We'll use the identity:
> \begin{align}
> &\int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
> {s\expo{st} \over \root{\pars{s + a}^3}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> =
> \int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}\expo{st}
> \bracks{{1 \over \pars{s + a}^{1/2}} - {a \over \pars{s + a}^{3/2}}}
> \,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}\expo{st}
> \braces{{1 \over \pars{s + a}^{1/2}}
> + 2a\,\partiald{}{a}\bracks{{1 \over \pars{s + a}^{1/2}}}}
> \,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \pars{1 + 2a\,\partiald{}{a}}\int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
> {\expo{st} \over \pars{s + a}^{1/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}\tag{1}
> \end{align}

In the complex plane $\pars{~s \in {\mathbb C}~}$, the
$\ds{\pars{s + a}^{-1/2}}$-branch-cut is defined by
$$
\pars{s + a}^{-1/2} = \verts{s + a}^{-1/2}\exp\pars{-\,{\phi \over 2}\,\ic}\quad
\mbox{where}\quad
s \not= -a\quad\mbox{and}\quad\verts{\phi} < \pi
$$
such that
\begin{align}
&\int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
{\expo{st} \over \pars{s + a}^{1/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
-\int_{-\infty}^{-a}\pars{-x - a}^{-1/2}\
\overbrace{\exp\pars{-\,{\pi \over 2}\,\ic}}^{\ds{=\ -\ic}}\ \expo{xt}
\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
-\int_{-a}^{-\infty}\pars{-x - a}^{-1/2}\
\overbrace{\exp\pars{-\,{\bracks{-\pi} \over 2}\,\ic}}^{\ds{=\ \ic}}\
\expo{xt}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,{1 \over \pi}\int_{-a}^{-\infty}\pars{-x - a}^{-1/2}\expo{xt}\,\dd x
=
{1 \over \pi}\int_{a}^{\infty}\pars{x - a}^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
{\expo{-at} \over \pi}\
\overbrace{\qquad\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/2}\expo{-xt}\,\dd x\qquad}^{\ds{=\ t^{-1/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2} = \root{\pi/t}}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> \int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
> {\expo{st} \over \pars{s + a}^{1/2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> =
> {\expo{-at} \over \root{\pi t}}\,,\qquad t > 0
> \end{align}

With the identity $\pars{1}$:
$$
\int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
{s\expo{st} \over \root{\pars{s + a}^{3}}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
=
\pars{1 + 2a\,\partiald{}{a}}{\expo{-at} \over \root{\pi t}}
=
{1 \over \root{\pi}}\,{\pars{1 - 2at}\expo{-at} \over \root{t}}
$$

> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \int_{\gamma -\ic\infty}^{\gamma + \ic\infty}
> {s\expo{st} \over \root{\pars{s + a}^{3}}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
> \color{#000000}{\ =\ }
> {1 \over \root{\pi}}\,{\pars{1 - 2at}\expo{-at} \over \root{t}}
> \,,\qquad\color{#000000}{t > 0}}$$